# Como pegar o conteúdo de uma textarea e mostrar em um modal

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp, aspx

Gostaria de saber se eu consigo pegar o conteúdo de uma textarea (que no caso é uma TexBox) e mostrar em um modal, no meu caso:

Segue o código que eu fiz:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="text-bold" Text="Informe as unidades a serem verificadas"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox TabIndex="1" runat="server" ID="txtDevice" CssClass="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Unidade" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="120px" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDevice" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Campo obrigatório!" ValidationGroup="btnBuscar" Display="Dynamic" />
```

e mais abaixo no mesmo arquivo, o modal (que eu chamo quando clica em um botão)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPointerCargo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalPointerCargo" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content panel-padrao">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </i>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                QUERO MOSTRAR O CONTÉUDO DO CAMPO AQUI
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando WebForm? Se sim você deve fazer a atribuição no back end da página, da seguinte forma:

Front end:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Back end:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     txtData.Text = "Seu texto";

  }
```

Você pode adicionar um novo label no seu modal, "txtmodal" e no back end você faz a atribuição, no evento que você deseja:

```
protected void seuBotao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    txtmodal.Text = txtDevice.Text;
}
```

EDIT: Para entender o comportamento, faça o seguinte teste:

Crie um novo projeto e no arquivo Default.aspx, troque todo o conteúdo da tag `<asp:Content>` para o seguinte:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="teste"></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

O evento do botão deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = Label1.Text;
        }
```

Se você testar verá que o texto da label2 é substituído pelo texto da label1. Entendendo esse comportamento você pode ajustar seu projeto para funcionar.

Comment: Fiz o que tu me disse, mas não funcionou, seria algo assim? (Eu estou fazendo perguntas bem simples porque estou iniciando os estudos disso tem essa semana)

<div class="modal-body">
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtModal"></asp:Label>
</div>

e o back end

protected void ButtonPC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   txtModal.Text = txtDevice.Text;
  }

Comment: Isso mesmo, vou editar a resposta pra vc fazer um teste.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).